# Combine TabBar and Navigation Bar how to pushViewController?

Tags: iphone

I drag a TabBar controller into "MainWindow.xib", then put a Navigation controller into TabBar controller, So one of my tab page is navigation page.
   I set the root view of Navigation Controller   (NavRootviewController.h / .m)

Give me one way to call -pushViewController: animated: ?

Comment: Thank you.
But i mean ,  i use the MyProjectAppDelegate.h as my view controller of navigation controller, just can't work. 
I do like this:
@interface MyProjectAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
        UIWindow *window;
 UITabBarController * tabBarController;
 UINavigationController *naviagtionController;
}

Comment: Then control-drag the "MyProjectApp Delegate" icon to NavigationController icon, and select outlet navScheduleController.
So i think the delegate file should be the view controller of navigation Controller too(not just TabBarController), but i can't call pushViewController: method like this:

[self.navigationController pushViewController: controller animated:YES];
also
[self.tabBarController.naviagtionController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
Thank you for your help,help me again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll typically call pushViewController:animated: from your view controller in response to a button click, or in a method like tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.  If you're pushing a UITableViewController subclass for example, you could do something like this in your root view controller:

```
YourTableViewController *controller = [[[YourTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
// Maybe set some properties on your controller here.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Could you tell me if i drag a UINavigate Controller to my mainWindow, it means it has create an object named navigationController by default?Thank you!

Comment: Hey,Thank you so much , i found my problem is.